# Count number of occurences of particular numbers in list

Tags: counting, rounding

I have a list of numbers which I have rounded and now all numbers are divisible by 5.

```
    napajecky=Round[{0.227`, 0.155`, 0.184`, 0.178`, 0.248`, 0.106`, 0.295`, 0.286`, 0.126`, 0.109`, 0.172`, 0.364`, 0.131`, 0.268`, 0.3`, 0.172`, 
   0.324`, 0.359`, 0.52`, 0.277`, 0.169`, 0.303`, 0.169`, 0.097`, 
   0.265`, 0.063`, 0.262`, 0.19`, 0.095`, 0.059`, 0.035`, 0.051`, 
   0.163`, 0.099`, 0.038`, 0.093`, 0.16`, 0.1454`, 0.3803`, 0.2437`, 
   0.0359`, 0.0959`, 0.0346`, 0.136`, 0.275`, 0.003`, 0.004`, 0.003`, 
   0.003`, 0.005`, 0.1686`, 0.1031`}*100, 5]
```

Now, I need to make a new list which would count number of occurences of numbers divisible by 5 in the rounded list and link it with that particular number. So the new list would look like this e.g.:
newlist={number of occurence of number 5 is 7, number of occurences of number 10 is 8,number of occurences of number 15 is 12, ... etc.}

I tried to define function that would count these occurences in certain range (5 to 80) but it does´t work:

```
f[x_]:=Count[x,Range[5,80,5]
res=f/@napajecky
```

Can you help me to find the best way?
Thank you for advice.

Comment: `BinCounts` and `Counts` would be useful here.

Comment: See [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html) which is included in the `See Also` section of the documentation for [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
BinCounts[napajecky, {0,85,5}]
(*    {5, 7, 8, 12, 3, 6, 7, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}    *)
```

Notice that the range goes to 85 so that the last bin is $[80,85)$ (from 80 inclusive to 85 exclusive).

Alternatively you could bin directly, without rounding first:

```
napajecky = {0.227, 0.155, 0.184, 0.178, 0.248, 0.106, 0.295, 0.286,
             0.126, 0.109, 0.172, 0.364, 0.131, 0.268, 0.3, 0.172, 0.324,
             0.359, 0.52, 0.277, 0.169, 0.303, 0.169, 0.097, 0.265, 0.063, 
             0.262, 0.19, 0.095, 0.059, 0.035, 0.051, 0.163, 0.099, 0.038,
             0.093, 0.16, 0.1454, 0.3803, 0.2437, 0.0359, 0.0959, 0.0346,
             0.136, 0.275, 0.003, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 0.005, 0.1686, 0.1031};

BinCounts[napajecky, {-0.025, 0.825, 0.05}]
(*    {5, 7, 8, 12, 3, 6, 7, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}    *)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
res = Lookup[Counts[napajecky], Range[5, 80, 5], 0]
```

> {7, 8, 12, 3, 6, 7, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Answer (score 4):

For completeness' sake, `Tally`:

```
Range[5, 80, 5] /. Append[Rule @@@ Tally[napajecky], _Integer -> 0]
```

> `{7, 8, 12, 3, 6, 7, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`